# Add a Object into state with array of Object by Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

when my backend send a payload with value:

```
Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "621ef5eec33b5c6d9d184563",
  "category": "621ef5e8c33b5c6d9d18455e",
  "createdAt": "2022-03-02T04:43:26.834Z",
  "description": "",
  "name": "Hair and Nails",
  "price": 50,
  "updatedAt": "2022-03-02T04:43:26.834Z",
},
```

How to add this Object to my serviceReducer
const initialState = {
isLoading: false,
error: false,
serviceCategories: [], //! serviceCategories is a Array
};
first of all, I map serviceCategories and selected serviceCategories that I need

```
        return {
            ...state,
            serviceCategories: state.serviceCategories.map((serviceCateogory) => {
                return serviceCateogory._id === action.payload.category 
                ? serviceCateogory //! here How I to add that object to services of serviceCateogory
                : serviceCateogory;
            }),
            // ),
        };
```

this is Structure of serviceCategories:

```
[
 Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "621ef5e8c33b5c6d9d18455e",
  "createdAt": "2022-03-02T04:43:20.754Z",
  "name": "Category1",
  "services": Array [
    Object {
      "__v": 0,
      "_id": "621ef5eec33b5c6d9d184563",
      "category": "621ef5e8c33b5c6d9d18455e",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-02T04:43:26.834Z",
      "description": "",
      "name": "Service1",
      "price": 50,
      "updatedAt": "2022-03-02T04:43:26.834Z",
    },
    Object {
      "__v": 0,
      "_id": "621ef7d1c33b5c6d9d1845b1",
      "category": "621ef5e8c33b5c6d9d18455e",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-02T04:51:29.262Z",
      "description": "",
      "name": "Service2",
      "price": 50,
      "updatedAt": "2022-03-02T04:51:29.262Z",
    },
  ],
  "updatedAt": "2022-03-02T05:08:35.520Z",
},
 Object {
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "621ef5e8c33b5c6d9d18455e",
  "createdAt": "2022-03-02T04:43:20.754Z",
  "name": "Category2",
....
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first findIndex of the specific category from the redux state and then append the service in it.
Like:

```
let categories=[...state.serviceCategories];     
let catIndex=categories.findIndex((item)=>item._id===action.payload.category);
if(catIndex!=-1) categories[catIndex].services.push(object); // append object (service) as you wish.
state.serviceCategories=categories;
```

Comment: I too try this way, but when I use "push" and "return" cmd then it make a warning,
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.]
I dont know How to fix that,

Comment: Are you using redux toolkit?

Comment: yep, i am using Redux Toolkit for my Project.

Comment: In redux toolkit we dont have to return new state object as it does automatically. So if you want to change the specific state just use state.entity=newValue; I have changed the code please follow it

Comment: @victhangnguyen issue fixed now?

Comment: Thank you so much...,  I know Redux toolkit supports this, But many times using return new state is fine, making me imagized it support too. I need to read a lot about Toolkit documentation again, once Thank you again.

Comment: Could you answer a side question, please?
What do you think about when State of Redux contains 1 larger data, it make Decrease the optimization or Limited of the app?
Ex specific my serviceCategories: if Customer make more Category and Service it will make State become Big data.